# Check if a value exists in an array of Dictionaries swift 3

Tags: swift

I have an array of dictionaries called `arrayOfDict` which contains a number of dictionary objects all with the same keys: `QUESTIONID` and `OPTIONID`.

```
[ //arrayOfDict
   {QUESTIONID:1, OPTIONID:0},
   {QUESTIONID:2, OPTIONID:201},
   {QUESTIONID:3, OPTIONID:204)
 ];
```

I need to add such dictionaries to `arrayOfDict` only if the dictionary I am adding does not contain the same `QUESTIONID`. If the `QUESTIONID` already exists then the corresponding `OPTIONID` needs to be replaced with new one. How can I compare my `QUESTIONID` with the `QUESTIONID` in `arrayOfDict` ?

Comment: Do not add arbitrary tags. This has nothing to do with Objective-C, iOS, the iPhone, or Xcode.

Comment: okay will keep in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try to get the index of the same question dic, if you get it, remove, else just insert it, try this:

```
if let index = array.index(where: {$0["QUESTIONID"] == dic["QUESTIONID"]}) {
        array.remove(at: index)
    }
    array.append(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
var dict = arrayOfDict.map { dictionary -> ([String : Int]) in
                var dicti = dictionary
                if dicti["QUESTIONID"] == 1 { // You can change 1 with whatever `QUESTIONID` you want to check
                    dicti["OPTIONID"] = 1 // You can change 1 with whatever value you want to assign for `OPTIONID`
                }
                return dicti
            }
print(dict)
```